# Deleting in Db4o Database Using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, db4o

I have a problem with deleting from my Db4o database. At the moment i can store new objects and get them shown in a datagrid view. But for some reason i cannot delete the objects again. Here is the Linq i am using.

```
public void DeleteStudent(int ssn)
    {
        var config = Db4oFactory.NewConfiguration();
        using (var db = Db4oFactory.OpenFile(config, "StudentDB"))
        {
            var query = (from StudentDB x in db
                         where x.SSN == ssn
                         select x);
            if (query != null)
            {
                db.Delete(query);
            }

        }
    }
```

I am getting the object that i want to delete by the ssn. I have tried debug and check that its not null and its not. I am getting the right object.

Here is the GUI part i am using.

```
private void btnDeleteStudent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ssn = Convert.ToInt32(txtSSN.Text);
        studentDB.DeleteStudent(ssn);

        gridStudents.DataSource = studentDB.GetAllStudents();
        ClearBoxes(this);
    }
```

i am getting the ssn from a textbox and giving it as a parameter when i click the delete button. And after that i am refreshing the gridview.

Hope one of you can help! i am new to Db4o so dont know a lot about it.

Comment: I have also tried with db.Commit(); after the delete statment.

Comment: Why the downvote?  It was asked well and he provided source code of what he tried.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong object to the db.

change your code to something  like:

```
using (var db = Db4oFactory.OpenFile(config, "StudentDB"))
{
    var query = (from StudentDB x in db
                 where x.SSN == ssn
                 select x).SingleOrDefault();

     if (query != null)
     {
        db.Delete(query);
     }
     db.Commit();
}
```